# not able to tap on item in google autocomplete list on iOS Ionic 3 application

Tags: ios, angular, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 to build an application. here's my code for goggle maps autocomplete api

in Html:

```
      <input id="pac-input" name="address" type="text" (keyup)="onKeyup()" [(ngModel)]="address" placeholder="Your street, building number..." class="name_txt" (click)="selectedSavedAddress = false" required />
```

in ts:

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var options = {
      types: ['geocode'], 
      componentRestrictions: {country: "SG"}
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
     console.log(autocomplete, 'autocomplete');

    var local_this = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var address = place.formatted_address;
      var postal_code_find = _.find(place.address_components, (ac: any) => {
        return ac.types[0] === 'postal_code';
      });
      var postal_code = '';

      postal_code_find && (postal_code = postal_code_find.short_name);

      var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

      let coord = {
        lat: latitude, 
        lng: longitude
      };

      let address_data = {
        address: address,
        postal_code: postal_code || ''
      };

      local_this.extractAddressData(address_data);
      local_this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
```

it's working fine in browser and android. In iOS I am able to see the suggestions but not able to tap on it. I have tried a lot of solutions like adding classes to pac-item such as no-fastclick, needsclick.
Nothing is working please help!!!

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: No I ended up making a custom list.

Answer (score 0):

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/ionic-webview@beta
```